# How add milliseconds in NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I have a Core Data which I have a attribute for my entity called `time` of `NSDate` type which contains time when was added in store.

When I'm trying to extract the data I need to be ordered by added time and I am using a `NSSortDescriptor`. My problem is when I have two or more entries with same time for example:

```
time = "2015-12-15 12:48:08 +0000";
time = "2015-12-15 12:48:08 +0000";
time = "2015-12-15 12:48:09 +0000";
time = "2015-12-15 12:48:09 +0000";
```

Here the order will be lost, because i don't have miliseconds in `NSDate`.

How can i fix that problem?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time"
                                                               ascending:YES];

[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
NSError *error;

NSArray *arr =[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

EDIT!
Declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * time;
```

Initialization:

```
newContact.time = [NSDate date];
```

And second type of initialization is:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSString *timeString = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]    

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];

NSDate *sentTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];
newContact.time = sentTime;
```

Comment: Could you tell us how you add years, month, days, hours, minutes and seconds in `NSDate`?

Comment: An `NSDate` contains milliseconds, assuming the original input had that resolution.  Is `time` really an `NSDate` or is it an `NSString`?

Comment: I did an edit for your question

Answer (score 1):

NSDate does contains milliseconds.

> Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval
>   relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January
>   2001).

The unit from this reference date is an `NSTimeInterval` that is a `double` with contains milliseconds in the decimal part.

> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields
>   sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

NSDate is created by using NSTimeInterval using his designated initializer `-initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)seconds`. Here is what happens if I call this method one right after the other:

```
        var interval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        print("\(interval)")
        interval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        print("\(interval)")

//        471879256.255005
//        471879256.259943
```

Now, CoreData can save directly NSDate object, my questions are:

- Are you saving NSDate or the formatted string?
- How those dates are created? from string? if they are from string are you reading them correctly?
- Pay attention that what you are printing is a string representation, if you want to print the real value you should ask the `-timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` property and you can be sure that the descriptor is sorting by using it.

I really doubt in CoreData saving NSDate rounding the values.

Comment: right after sentTime creation write that and check if it has decimal values NSLog(@"Interval %lf", sentTime.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate); if doesn't the date format is wrong or the string that you are trying to convert in NSDate it doesn't expose millisec

Comment: Interval 471881576.851000,  so?

Comment: As you can see it does contain milliseconds, everything seems correct, maybe the problem is elsewhere. To check if the sorter is sorting correctly I would print the timeintervalsincerefdate instead of the date description.

Comment: You can see how NSSortDescriptor is created. Have an idea where can be the problem?